# Play 2 Framework include dynamic path to include configuration

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to include a configuration file which its location is set by environment variable.

for example:

```
include "file:///<ENVVAL>prod.conf"
```

I am not sure how i am supposed to concatenate the string

any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally in HOCON, environment variables can be interpolated using the `${ENVVAL}` syntax. However, this is explicitly **not supported** in arguments to `include` (see [this section](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#includes) in the docs.)

Note that you can specify a configuration file (or resource) by setting the `config.file` or `config.resource` properties via `-D` JVM args, which is normally how you'd specify a production config.  A prod config can then  `include` the application.conf resource containing common configuration for dev and prod.

See the [Configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration) docs for more details.